# Named query failing to parse map

Tags: go

I have this code segement

```
query := `
        SELECT
            co_username as username,
            co_password as password
        FROM
            servers.co
        WHERE
            co_url = concat('https://', :co_url)
    `

    args := map[string]interface{}{
        "co_url": in.Url,
    }

    rows, err := collectorsConfig.Db.NamedQueryContext(ctx, query, args)
    if err != nil {
        msg := "Error getting co credentials for co '%s': %v"
        log.Error.Printf(msg, in.Url, err)
        return
    }
```

When runnig this snippet, I get an error like this:

> Error getting co credentials for co 'some.random.fqdn': could not find
>   name  in map[string]interface {}{"co_url":"some.random.fqdn"}

But if I rework the snippet to be

```
in.Url = "https://" + in.Url

query := `
            SELECT
                co_username as username,
                co_password as password
            FROM
                servers.co
            WHERE
                co_url = :co_url
        `
```

Everything works. Is there a reason the named input is not working with the `Concat` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend on what `sql` library you are using, but when using `NamedQuery` in many libraries, you **must** escape any other colons, which you will find how to do in its documentation. For example, [`sqlx`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) requires you to escape a colon with two e.g.

```
co_url = concat('https:://', :co_url)
```